# AWS Athena - Querying a particular time period

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a data which has two time based columns - date, hour (other columns are present). My aim is to read data for a particular time period.

**Data**:

```
date         hour
22-06-20      0
22-06-20      1
..            ..
23-06-20      23
```

**Aim**: Read data between 22-06-20 4th hour to 23-06-20 4th hour.

**Query I have is:**

```
select date, hour from mytable where
date >= date("22-06-20")
and hour >= 4;
```

The above would give me data from 22-06-20 4th hour to 23-06-20 23rd hour. But how to stop it with 4th hour of 23-06-20.

I have shown a hard coded example above, however what I am trying is in real time as my table gets updated hourly.

```
select date, hour from mytable  where
date >= date(current_timestamp - interval '25' hour)
and hour >= hour(current_timestamp - interval '25' hour)
```

Why I am doing -25 hours is I want last 24 hours data excluding the last hour i.e say now is 10th hour of 23-06-20. I want data from 22-06-20 9th to 23-06-20 9th. Trying to solve the above query should help me do this as well.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your date is really a timestamp:

```
where date >= timestamp '2020-06-20 04:00:00' and
      date < timestamp '2020-06-23 04:00:00'
```

EDIT:

Oh, I see.  They are in two different columns.  So you can do:

```
where (date = '2020-06-20' and hour >= 4) or
      (date > '2020-06-20' and date < '2020-06-23') or
      (date = '2020-06-23' and hour < 4)
```

Comment: No my date is not a timestamp, its just only the date.